# Using objects with IntegerProperty fields as a key in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a class A with automatically generated hashCode() and equals() methods:

```
public class A {

private IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private IntegerProperty y = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
    this.x.set(x);
    this.y.set(y);
}

public int getX() {
    return x.get();
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x.set(x);
}

public int getY() {
    return y.get();
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y.set(y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((x == null) ? 0 : x.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((y == null) ? 0 : y.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    A other = (A) obj;
    if (x == null) {
        if (other.x != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!x.equals(other.x))
        return false;
    if (y == null) {
        if (other.y != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!y.equals(other.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}
...
}
```

And an enumeration:

```
public enum E {
S1,S2;
...
}
```

In my main method I have the following HashMap:

```
private ObservableMap<A, E> m = FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<>());
A a1 = new A(0,0);
A a2 = new A(0,0);
E e1 = E.S1;
    
m.put(a1, e1);
System.out.println(m.get(a1)); // S1
System.out.println(m.get(a2)); // null
```

I suppose it's the `equals()` method which is broken, because normally with int values instead of IntegerPropertiy the second `println(...)` shouldn't print `null`.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: You seem to be expecting two SimpleIntegerPropertys to be equal just because they currently hold the same value. I don't think that's the way they work.

Comment: „fs“ is used in your println, but it is not defined

Comment: This is `null` because you don't have a key in your map, you didn't put any `a2` to your map.

Comment: @khelwood Hmmmm okay. But I have to use them. Do you know a solution for my problem?

Comment: You could use the value of the property in your equals and hashcode implementations. As long as you're not going to change the values of those properties while your A instance is inside the hashmap.

Comment: @AlexRudenko Guessing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting two SimpleIntegerPropertys to be equal just because they currently hold the same value.

Going by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html that doesn't seem to be how they work.

Instead you could use the *values* from those properties in your equals and hashcode methods.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getX(), getY());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this==o) return true;
    if (o==null || o.getClass()!=this.getClass()) return false;
    A that = (A) o;
    return (this.getX()==that.getX() && this.getY()==that.getY());
}
```

This way two instances of A with the same values for x and y will be equal. (However, if you alter those values while your object is a key in a hashmap, the hashmap won't work properly. That's the downside of value-based equals/hashcode implementations.)